# Is there any way to pass Global Properties from external file or something?

Tags: groovy, soapui

-Is there any way to pass Global Properties from external file or something?
-I don't want to navigate Preference-Global Properties and changing the values.
-Is there any alternative way to do this.

Thanks,
Arivazhagan

Comment: There is this: https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/working-with-properties.html#2-Setting-properties-from-the-command-line

Comment: What happened when you tried what @SiKing suggested?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse external file in groovy script Step, for example *.csv file with values into the local groovy variables, and then set value in Properties of Test Suite or Test Case or Global Properties too.

Example of parsing *.csv file:

```
def testDataSet = []
def index = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("index")
int indx = index.toInteger()
def fileName = "phoneNumbers.csv"
//read from file
new File(fileName).eachLine { line -> testDataSet.add( line.split(";") ) }
log.info( "Read " + testDataSet.size() + " test values from " + fileName )
//convert value to properties
def testDataLine = testDataSet[indx]
phoneNumber = testDataLine[0].value as String
log.info phoneNumber
```

Example of set property:

```
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("phoneNumber", phoneNumber)
indx++
String indexString = Integer.toString(indx)
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("index", indexString)
```

Example of set Global Preporty:

```
globalProperty = com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties.getPropertyValue( "MyProp" )
```

more info provide here https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/tips-tricks.html

Answer (score 0):

Global properties are stored in soapui-settings.xml in the user.dir. If you change it, it will be recognized by readyApi/soapUI.